# Choppy scrolling in Google Chrome due to width:100% attribute

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am using a different background image for each page on my site using the HTML below:

```
<div class="bg_img">
<img src="images/bg1.jpg" alt="background" />
</div>
```

When using the site in IE and Firefox there is no problem but when using in Chrome there is a choppy / lag effect when scrolling.

I realised that when I remove the `width:100%` property the lag stops but I need it to scale the background images.

```
.bg_img img{
width:100%;  <---- PROBLEM
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Is there something I could do to get around using `width:100%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would totally change the approach to a full page background. There are better solutions than just setting a 100% which will ultimately cause a wrong image ratio.
Here's a way you could try.

```
.bg_img img{
  background: url(bg_img.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
```

You can read more about full page backgrounds [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I ended up using this jQuery plug-in. It worked pretty well. http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/425/jQuery-Easy-Background-Resize

Answer (score 0):

These days, with [all modern browsers supporting it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts), I would suggest using a background image instead, and using something like this:

```
background-size: cover;
```

That will keep the background image on the `<body>` element as wide as the screen. (For older, dodo browsers, you can just center it.)

There are options other than `cover`, but I suspect that's what will work best for you.